# Função anônima retorna: syntax error, unexpected T_FUNCTION

Tags: php, expressões-lambda, função-anônima

Ao tentar usar esta função:

```
<?php
echo preg_replace_callback('~-([a-z])~', function ($match) {
    return strtoupper($match[1]);
}, 'hello-world');
```

o PHP retorna este erro:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_FUNCTION

Como resolver?

Comment: **Relacionado:** [Posso responder minha própria pergunta?](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) e [Accept Your Own Answers](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/01/accept-your-own-answers/)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Se está recebendo este erro é por que o seu PHP é uma versão "antiga". Funções anonimas estão disponíveis desde PHP 5.3.0.

Fonte:

http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/functions.anonymous.php

### Verificar versão do PHP:

Para verificar qual a versão do PHP está rodando na sua máquina ou servidor crie um arquivo e adicionando isto ao conteúdo:

```
<?php
phpinfo();
```

Também é possível fazer isto por linha de comando, digite no terminal ou SSH:

`php -i` ou `php -v`

Se necessita manter compatibilidade com versões mais antigas que o 5.3 pode simplesmente fazer isto:

```
<?php
function MeuReplace($match) {
    return strtoupper($match[1]);
}

echo preg_replace_callback('~-([a-z])~', 'MeuReplace', 'hello-world');
```